# How to use the & character in T-SQL's XML type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, escaping

When I run:

```
SELECT name + '&' 
FROM sys.databases 
FOR XML PATH('');
```

The code returns this:

```
master&amp;tempdb&amp;model&amp;msdb&amp;
```

What I really want is:

```
master&tempdb&model&msdb&
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT name + CHAR(38) 
FROM sys.databases 
FOR XML PATH('');
```

This doesn't work, too. How can I get the expected result in the first place?

Without something like:

```
REPLACE(CAST('master&amp...l&amp;msdb&amp;' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '&amp;', '&')
```

Comment: Try: `SELECT (SELECT name + '&' FROM sys.databases FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)');`

Comment: Glad to help, @OgrishMan. I expanded on my comment with an answer. As the proverb says, give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FOR XML` clause returns text by default so the result string includes XML predefined entity references, such as `&amp;` for an ampersand, to represent special characters within the XML.

To avoid entity references in the result, include `TYPE` in the `FOR XML` clause to return the value as strongly-typed XML instead of text, which allows invocation of a `value` method on the XML node to get the value as `nvarchar(MAX)` without the entity references:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT name + '&'
    FROM sys.databases
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)');
```

The above example includes a trailing ampersand like your original query. One way to avoid the extraneous delimiter is with `STUFF`. Below is another example that prepends the delimiter to each value and removes the unneeded first one. Also, the singleton node value `(./text())[1]` specification will improve performance, a consideration
for larger queries.

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT '&' + name
    FROM sys.databases
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
```

I'll add that you can avoid the XML ugliness for aggregate string concatenation in SQL Server 2017+ and Azure SQL Database using a much cleaner and less verbose `STRING_AGG` technique:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(name, '&')
FROM sys.databases;
```

See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax) for a more detailed description of string aggegation using `FOR XML`.